# What's the relationship between X-Wing pilot Porkins' name and appearance?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

So, not be insensitive, but in *A New Hope* there's an (aptly named?) X-Wing pilot named Porkins.

[image]

What's the story here?  Possibilities:

- complete coincidence
- the character was named in the script and it influenced the casting director
- the character's name and appearance were mentioned in the script
- the character's appearance was mentioned in the script and the name was ad libbed or scripted later
- etc...

What information is available on how this all played out?

Comment: In-universe, it's just coincidence that his name is Porkins and he's overweight. His in-universe nickname of "Piggy", however...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPm1O.png - Star Wars Insider #32.

Comment: My avatar takes offence from this question (notice my pic). Really tempted to downvote (but didn't).

Comment: https://mikescollection.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/sw-porkins-front-e1331936228779.jpg?w=599&h=1024

Comment: There's also the fact that the fat guy named "Porkins" is the *worst* of the X-Wing pilots.  (He's the only one shot down by fire from the fixed turbo-laser turrets; the others have to be destroyed ship-to-ship.)

Comment: Nominative determinism?

Comment: @Buzz - In the original script he was described as an expert pilot and got shot down by a TIE fighter ace.

Answer (score 2):

**All signs point to the character of Porkins being created *before*
William "Bill" Hootkins was cast for the role, then his being assigned
the role once he'd agreed to play a pilot.**

---

William "Bill" Hootkins was originally offered the role of Jabba the Hutt but declined it in favour of another role that he had auditioned for (that of Mr. Fatty in [Valentino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentino_(1977_film))), returning to the set of Star Wars and filming his scenes between June 29th and July 16th, 1976.

According to [*The Making of Star Wars*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Making_of_Star_Wars:_The_Definitive_Story_Behind_the_Original_Film), in late April 1976 it became apparent to Lucas that they were short of X-wing pilots and calls went out to actors who'd successfully auditioned but declined roles, including Hootkins. When he arrived on set he was bemused to learn that his character's name was Porkins, [initially thinking that he was going to be given a pig-like makeover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPm1O.png).

The character of Porkins appears in the [Fourth Draft](https://web.archive.org/web/20180223214655/http://www.starwarz.com/starkiller/star-wars-the-adventures-of-luke-starkiller-revised-fourth-draft/) script (dated March 1976), written *before he had agreed to play an X-wing pilot*. Lucas and his casters would undoubtedly have been aware of Bill Hootkins' size and stature, making him an obvious choice for Porkins, described in the script as having the nickname *"Blue Pig"*.

Based on the timelines, it's clear that the role of "Porkins" wasn't *specifically written for Hootkins*, nor was Hootkins *specifically cast for the role of Porkins*, as he was simply one of several actors called in to do fill-in shots as pilots, however, once he'd agreed to play a role, he was the obvious choice for the overweight pilot envisioned by Lucas in his script.

Comment: I feel like the answer to the question we are looking for is "Yes, Porkins was supposed to be fat."

Comment: @JDoe - I suspect that the answer was more, **Casting Guy #1:** *Who's next?, **Casting Guy #2** *Well, we've got a fat guy who can play Porkins. Cross him off the casting list*

Comment: Good choice; Jabba got cut anyway.